# Is there any way of finding out the printable area of a specific page type for a printer?

Tags: printing, word-processing, publishing

This relates to my other question, [Word Processor Margins versus Printable Area of Paper](https://superuser.com/questions/549923/word-processor-margins-versus-printable-area-of-paper). Is there any source of information that will give the real printer margins for a standard paper size, for a standard print type, for a particular printer? Or, is there a way to query your word processor for this information? It is able to adjust its own margins to match the printer marings (printable area), so the information can somehow be and is communicated.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that in MS Word 97/2003 you could "query" the printer margins (as coded into the driver probably) simply by reducing the page margins to zero in the `Page Setup` dialog. After clicking `OK`, there was an error dialog saying that the margins are too small. But you had the option to "correct" the values and voilà, all margins are adjusted to the maximum possible.
I cannot check if this is still working in current version of Word -- however in LibreOffice it still works, very similar procedure as described above.

Comment: When I try by installing only a printer driver, and no physical device, I only get warned that my margins are very small, and asked if I want to proceed. There is no 'Fix' option. This makes me think that sometimes the printer can tell the computer it's margin dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps you have to choose a specific printer model inside the driver, often it's a complete driver "suite", same here with Kyocera KX Driver. But it indeed tells the margins, perhaps because I selected the FS-3800 model. Btw. the only driver I know so far with really zero margins is the MS XPS Writer. --- About the warning you get. In LibreOffice it's similar, and you had to say "Proceed? No!" and the margins get corrected.